# I have a problem in navigation in react-native while using the Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation

1. I want to navigate to a new page when the email and password is correct(when click the button) .
2. ie while click button I i want to check API and navigate to another page ,if email and password is
   correct
3. Here I use AXIOS for API integration.

---------This is my code----------

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const NewsCard = ()=>{

  
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
   const[name ,setName] = useState('namesssssssss')
    return(       
        <View>   
            <Text>{name}</Text> 
            <TextInput
          
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onChangeText={ (text) => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
        />

        <TextInput
         
          
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={(pswrd) => setPassword(pswrd)}
          value={password}
        />
            <Button onPress={ ()=>
axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login',
{
  email: email,
  password: password,
})
.then(function (response) {
  // handle success
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  alert('Wrong Email or Password');
})
.then(function () {
})
           } title="Click"></Button>
        </View>   
    )
}

export default NewsCard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const NewsCard = ()=>{

  
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
   const[name ,setName] = useState('namesssssssss')
    return(       
        <View>   
            <Text>{name}</Text> 
            <TextInput
          
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onChangeText={ (text) => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
        />

        <TextInput
         
          
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={(pswrd) => setPassword(pswrd)}
          value={password}
        />
            <Button onPress={ ()=>
axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login',
{
  email: email,
  password: password,
})
.then(function (response) {
  // handle success
  navigation.navigate('SomeComponent');
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  alert('Wrong Email or Password');
})
.then(function () {
})
           } title="Click"></Button>
        </View>   
    )
}

export default NewsCard
react-native
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Above code can fix your problem but it isn't a right way to do this.

To do this right, you should do this in Navigator

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import HomeStack from "./HomeStack"; //stack navigator which holds your actual app
import AuthStack from "./AuthStack"; //stack navigator which ables a user to login to your app

export const Navigator = () => {
  // some state that you may have declared in your reducers
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {auth.isLoggedIn ? <HomeStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

You can read more about `authentication flows` [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)

Comment: Thank you sir God bless you abundantly

Comment: sir ----- 1 . I use the link ("http://localhost:5000/api/admin/login") for fetch data from API using AXIOS.

2. But it shows network error in my emulator .

3 . so I use this (http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login) and it works.

4 . but when I use the same app in my mobile phone(Huwai y9 prime) it shows network error .

5 . ie at the same time it works in emulator but not in real Device.

-------------How should I solve this problem----------

Comment: Because your real device doesn't have access to your local environment. If you want to use your API in real device, you have expose the port, your API is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Calling an API request directly from Button is highly unadvised, but this solution should work

First Create a handle function for login , calling API from render (return) is bad practice.

**handleLogin**

```
const NewsCard = ()=>{

  
const navigation = useNavigation();

const handleLogin = () => {
  axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login',
{
  email: email,
  password: password,
})
.then(function (response) {
  // handle success
  navigation.navigate('RouteName');
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  alert('Wrong Email or Password');
})
.then(function () {
})
```

call it in the Button component

```
<Button onPress={handleLogin} title="Click"></Button>
```

That way your code will look way more readable and clean

Comment: Thank you sir God bless you abundantly

Comment: sir ----- 1 . I use the link ("http://localhost:5000/api/admin/login") for fetch data from API using AXIOS.

2. But it shows network error in my emulator .

3 . so I use this (http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login) and it works.

4 . but when I use the same app in my mobile phone(Huwai y9 prime) it shows network error .

5 . ie at the same time it works in emulator but not in real Device.

-------------How should I solve this problem----------

Comment: are your computer(the one you are running the database) and the real device connected to same internet / wife router ?

Comment: yes both are connected in same internet, but still have problem

Comment: Seems like an issue of local and LAN configuration , what you can do is :
Open terminal and run "ipconfig" without the "  
Copy the IPv4 address from the data
replace the 10.0.2.2 with the address form cmd.

So your request address will look something like:  192.168.0.106:5000/api/admin/login

Comment: Thank You sir it's working Gob bless you abundantly